# Error al scrapear multiples paginas web: name 'chromeOptions' is not defined

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scraping, chromedriver

Estoy intentando scrapear una lista de webs. Iba scrapeando bien y devolviendo los datos hasta que apareció el error:

> Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist

Encontré una solución y mi código quedó asi:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

for i in datos:
    #browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
    chrome_options = Options()
    chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}) 
    chromeOptions.add_argument("--no-sandbox") 
    chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox") 

    chromeOptions.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")  # this

    chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-using") 
    chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-extensions") 
    chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-gpu") 
    chromeOptions.add_argument("start-maximized") 
    chromeOptions.add_argument("disable-infobars")
    chromeOptions.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=.\cookies\\test") 

    b= webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions) 
    wait = WebDriverWait(b, 10)
    browser.get(i)

    b = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions) 
    b.quit()
```

Pero recibo el error

> Error: name 'chromeOptions' is not defined

Alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

Comment: Tienes `chrome_options = Options()
    chromeOptions.add_experimental_option`. chromeOptions no existe :)

Answer (score 1):

La solución mas simple que encontré fue evitar usar ChromeOptions (o Options) y eliminar `wait = WebDriverWait(b, 10)`